# How to remove '#' comments from a string?

Tags: string, python-3.x, comments

The problem:
Implement a Python function called stripComments(code) where code is a parameter that takes a string containing the Python code. The function stripComments() returns the code with all comments removed.

I have:

```
def stripComments(code):
   code = str(code)
   for line in code:
       comments = [word[1:] for word in code.split() if word[0] == '#']
       del(comments)
stripComments(code)
```

I'm not sure how to specifically tell python to search through each line of the string and when it finds a hashtag, to delete the rest of the line. 
Please help. :(

Comment: Consider `distutils.text_file.TextFile(file=io.StringIO(code)).readlines()` which uses [`TextFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.text_file) with [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this through `re.sub` function.

```
import re
def stripComments(code):
    code = str(code)
    return re.sub(r'(?m)^ *#.*\n?', '', code)

print(stripComments("""#foo bar
bar foo
# buz"""))
```

`(?m)` enables the multiline mode. `^` asserts that we are at the start. `<space>*#` matches the character `#` at the start with or without preceding spaces. `.*` matches all the following characters except line breaks. Replacing those matched characters with empty string will give you the string with comment lines deleted.

Comment: Note that this will not remove comments at the ends of active code lines.

Comment: note if a line of code were to contain '#' as part of the code this would also not work even if you fixed it to work after active code lines by removing the `^` from the regex string

Answer (score 2):

For my future reference.

```py
def remove_comments(lines: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines: 
        if line.startswith("#"):  # Deal with comment as the first character
            continue

        line = line.split(" #")[0]
        if line.strip() != "":
            new_lines.append(line)

    return new_lines


print(remove_comments("Hello #World!\n\nI have a question # that #".split('\n')))
>>> ['Hello', 'I have a question']
```

This implementation has benefit of not requiring the `re` module and being easy to understand. It also removes pre-existing blank lines, which is useful for my use case.

Comment: This would also detect hashes inside string literals as comments, which is probably not intended. I.e. if you `remove_comments` on the line in your code `line = line.split(" #")[0]` you would get `line = line.split("`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_comments(filename1, filename2):
    """ Remove all comments beginning with # from filename1 and writes
    the result to filename2
    """

    with open(filename1, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    with open(filename2, 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            # Keep the Shebang line
            if line[0:2] == "#!":
                f.writelines(line)
            # Also keep existing empty lines
            elif not line.strip():
                f.writelines(line)
            # But remove comments from other lines
            else:
                line = line.split('#')
                stripped_string = line[0].rstrip()
                # Write the line only if the comment was after the code.
                # Discard lines that only contain comments.
                if stripped_string:
                    f.writelines(stripped_string)
                    f.writelines('\n')
```

Comment: This would end up badly if # was contained in a string as part of the code

Answer (score 0):

```py
def removeComments(string: str):
    """Takes something like:

    import math

    math.pow(2,3) # 2 to the power of 3

    and outputs:

    import math
    
    math.pow(2,3) 

    Maintains trailing whitespace
    """
    isInComment=False
    returnVal = ""
    for char in string:
        if char == '#':
            isInComment=True
        elif char == "\n":
            isInComment=False
        if not isInComment:
            returnVal+=char
    return returnVal
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).