# How to remove all the # comment out line for many files?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I have some files and I want to remove all the code after # (comment out),

maybe I want to import all the file and copy it line by line and ignore the # lines

I don't know what kind of tool or langauge should I use.

For example

```
AAA
BBB
#123
#456
CCC
```

I hope I can get

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

but not

```
AAA
BBB


CCC
```

I tried to use regex to do replace the # line in "" but I doesn't work

```
str.replace(/\r/g,"")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGMd6.png)

I tried to detect what is the blue area, it said 6 spaces.

Comment: The question is marked both as JavaScript and Python - in which language would you like to have example code in any answers?

Comment: You can do this in almost any language. The regex you're looking for needs to remove anything that's "a new line starting with #, all the way to and including the next newline". So including support for both Unix-style and Windows-style newlines, as well as the first and last lines in a fiel, that's, `(?:^\r?\n)#.*?(?:\r?\n|$)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove '#' comments from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401547/how-to-remove-comments-from-a-string)

Comment: (And if you're not dedicated to Python, there's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350223/sed-remove-and-empty-lines-with-one-sed-command )  Welcome to the site! You may find a lot of your programming questions are already answered on SO, and you can get those answers more quickly be searching for them prior to asking a question.

Comment: I know Javascript more, but also know a little bit of Python

Comment: so do I still need to replact it in ""?

Answer (score 1):

As a related answer giving example python code has already been posted, here's a working solution in JavaScript. The RegEx pattern I use also matches Windows-style carriage return line breaks.

```js
var string = `AAA
BBB
#123
#456
CCC`;

console.log(string.replace(/^#.*\r?\n/gm, ''));
```